# Fontawesome icon doesn't update

Tags: javascript, vue.js, font-awesome

I've been trying a couple of things to get an icon (fontawesome) to update when data in an array changes in Vue JS.

This is my template

```
<div v-for="task in sortedTasks" class="box" >
        <span v-if="task.starred === 1">Starred</span>
        <span v-else >Not Starred</span>
        <label class="b-checkbox is-primary">
            <input id="task.id" name="select" :value="task.id" class="styled" type="checkbox">
            <label :for="task.id"></label>
        </label>
        <div class="spacer-left" style="display: inline-block;">{{task.title}}</div>
        <div class="is-pulled-right" style="display: inline-block;">
            <a v-if="task.starred === 1" @click="setStar(task)"><i class="far fa-star-exclamation fa-lg has-text-primary"></i></a>
            <a v-else @click="setStar(task)"><i class="far fa-star fa-lg has-text-primary"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="is-pulled-right" style="display: inline-block;">
            <span v-if="checkDueDate(task.due_date)" class="has-text-primary is-size-7 spacer-right">{{formatDueDate(task.due_date)}}</span>
            <span v-else class="has-text-danger is-size-7 spacer-right">{{formatDueDate(task.due_date)}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="is-pulled-right" style="display: inline-block;"><span class="is-size-7 spacer-right">{{task.assigned_to.name}}</span></div>
    </div>
```

And this is the setStar() method that is called when you click the star

```
setStar: function (task) {
    // find task in array and change to starred
   let ref = _.findIndex(this.tasks, {'id': task.id});
   console.log(ref);
    let star = this.tasks[ref].starred ?  0 : 1;
    this.$nextTick(function() {
      this.tasks[ref].starred = star;
    });


    // send api request to update database
    axios.post('api/tasks/star/toggle', {
      id: task.id,
      star: star
    }).then(r => {
      // do stuff here
    })


  },
```

The toggle works, as I have a label that I added to check, and this changes when click the star, however. the Icon remains the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: have u inspect element in your browser? does the class change ?

Comment: if the problem is related to a classname not changing then post the code that's supposed to change the classname. the javascript you posted is in no way relevant to the problem you described.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. surely the v-if  task.starred === 1 should change the anchor linked used. (which has the different font awesome classes).
I haven't used a method or computed property to update the class on this ocasion, as that didn't work either.

Comment: @JacobGoh when inspecting the element the "not starred" and "starred" text changes, but the anchor element with the fontawesome icon in doesn't

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about because you didn't post the full code. I have no clue what supposed to be in `this.tasks`.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. I didn't post the full code as its not relevant. There is an item in this.tasks called "starred". If that is set to 1 it show show: 

<i class="far fa-star-exclamation fa-lg has-text-primary"></i>

if set to 0, it should show: 

<i class="far fa-star fa-lg has-text-primary"></i>

Comment: @RWest - Based on *what*? Where is the code that listens for changes to that property and alters the DOM accordingly. It's JS dude, not magic. If you think that changing that property is somehow supposed to magically change the DOM then you need to show us what `this.tasks` is supposed to be.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. nice once on the sarcasm mate. not really required or appropriate.

Comment: There was precisely zero sarcasm in my last comment. It's a legitimate question. I'm trying to help you. At least I was, I'm not anymore. Good luck.

Comment: FA4? FA5 (CSS | SVG)?

Comment: Solved it - now using the FA5 webfonts css instead of svg and works perfectly fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why, but as soon as I switched to webfont css instead of svg, it works perfectly.

Comment: I had the same problem, I switched from using `v-if` to `v-show` and it works.